# Error in function when converting from c# to vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

Converted a function in C # to VB through an online converter. Basically this function allows you to open a folder on a server.

Original code in c# :

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load("cl.xml");


            var folderToFind = TextBox_ov.Text;

            var paths = doc.Descendants("dir")
                .Where(dir => string.Equals(folderToFind, (string)dir.Attribute("name"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .Select(dir => dir.AncestorsAndSelf().Select(el => (string)el.Attribute("name")).Reverse().Aggregate(string.Empty, Path.Combine))
            ;

            foreach (string path in paths)
            {
                Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = path,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    Verb = "open"
                });
            }
```

Code converted to VB:

```
Private Sub btn_open_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_open.Click

    Dim doc = XDocument.Load("cl.xml")
    Dim folderToFind = "ov" + TextBox_ov.Text
    Dim paths = doc.Descendants("dir").Where(Function(dir) String.Equals(folderToFind, CStr(dir.Attribute("name")), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).[Select](Function(dir) dir.AncestorsAndSelf().[Select](Function(el) CStr(el.Attribute("name"))).Reverse().Aggregate(String.Empty, Path.Combine))

    For Each path As String In paths
        Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo With {
            .FileName = path,
            .UseShellExecute = True,
            .Verb = "open"
        })
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm having this error:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, Integer, TResult)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function Aggregate(Of TAccumulate)(seed As TAccumulate, func As System.Func(Of TAccumulate, String, TAccumulate)) As TAccumulate' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error. \\bacserver\users\satbr\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Encomendas\Encomendas\Form1.vb    60  21  Encomendas
```

What is the problem?

Thank you,

Comment: The c# you are cast to a (string).  To do equivalent in VB.Net, use CType(object, string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the initialization of "path" to:

```
Dim paths = doc.Descendants("dir").Where(Function(dir) String.Equals(folderToFind, CStr(dir.Attribute("name")), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(Function(dir) dir.AncestorsAndSelf().Select(Function(el) CStr(el.Attribute("name"))).Reverse().Aggregate(String.Empty, AddressOf Path.Combine))
```

From what I can tell, it's just the "AddressOf" that you're missing. (Your code with the above change compiles for me).

(Using 'AddressOf' passes the function without actually calling the function).